# Printing data in python by parsing json

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to get the correct notation to parse json data and print the required output in python

here is a sample json file

Play info Json Response:

```
{
"id": 111,
"age": 22,
"Hobby": [
{
 "List": 1,
 "Sev": "medium",
 "name": "play 1",
 "game": "tennis",
},
{
 "List": 2,
 "Sev": "high",
 "name": "play 2",
 "game": "football",
},
{
 "List": 2,
 "Sev": "high",
 "name": "play 3",
 "game": "racing",
}
]
```

I am looking for python commands to print the outcome of play 2 ie, football from the json file..Appreciate the help.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in json library in Python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You will find help here, but this site has rules. As a new user, you really should read [ask] to understand what questions are acceptable and what are not. Here you are expected to show the code  for a *honest attempt* to solve the problem by yourself and explaining where you are stuck.

Comment: Without seeing your code and knowing what the "required output" is, this is impossible to answer. Also, your data do not represent valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
json = { "id": 111, "age": 22, "Hobby": [ 
    { "List": 1, "Sev": "medium", "name": "play 1", "game": "tennis", }, 
    { "List": 2, "Sev": "high", "name": "play 2", "game": "football", }, 
    { "List": 2, "Sev": "high", "name": "play 3", "game": "racing", } ]}


a = [hobby['game'] for hobby in json['Hobby'] if hobby['name'] == 'play 2']
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['football']
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to get only football as my output..

Comment: your question is bit confusing. But I edited the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks again..The above output is what I am looking for..
Can we parse [] from the output to just get the value..if possible. eg Output : 'football'